# How to restrict access to specific directories when using VSCode Live Share?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know you can add a `.vsls.json` file to exclude files, etc.  What isn't clear to me is if I can restrict directories.  The example given on the MS site is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/vsls",
  "gitignore":"none",
  "excludeFiles":[
      "*.p12",
      "*.cer",
      "token",
      ".gitignore"
  ],
  "hideFiles": [
      "bin",
      "obj"
  ]
}
```

And so it seems I can restrict access to the "token", "bin" and "obj" directories.

Does this prevent a participant from browsing outside of the directory structure for the project?

Is there a way to create a simpler declaration that only shares a single directory and no other?

The `.vsls.json` approach would have me list every single directory I am not sharing.  I have dozens of directories.  I would rather be able to take the opposite approach and not share anything unless explicitly shared.  This would allow me to, for example, share the "group_project" directory and not worry about any other in the hierarchy.

Is this possible?

Comment: add a feature request for a property `includeFiles`

Comment: strangely, .vsls.json doesn't seem to be working at all for me. anyhow, related docs for the interested: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/quickstart/share and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/security#controlling-file-access-and-visibility

Answer (score 0):

the strings are glob patterns.

What if you exclude all and then add a rule to reverse it for the directories you allow

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/vsls",
  "gitignore":"none",
  "excludeFiles":[
      "*",
      "!my-allow-dir",
      ".gitignore"
  ],
  "hideFiles": [
      "bin",
      "obj"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'll test this later today and report back.

Comment: Just got a chance to try it.  I does restrict the directory, However, the person on the other side sees it as empty.  I am going to experiment with a few exclude and hide ideas to see if I can get it to work

Comment: @martin's if it partially works I suggest you create an issue, they tell it should work the same as `.gitignore`, they should also block those directories from a list request, maybe `**` also matches directories and not only files, or `**/*`

Comment: I had to explicitly exclude everything else one directory and file type at a time.  So far this has been the only way to share only one directory out of the source tree.  I tried `**` in various forms.  I haven't found anything that works yet.  If I can't make it work I'll create an issue.

Comment: Also, unless I am wrong about this, the only way to have edits to `.vsls.json` take effect is to restart VSC.  That makes experimentation quite painful.  Is there a command to reload the file without restarting VSC?

Comment: @martin's What if you execute **Developer: Reload Window**, if they can make the other folders empty, it might be considered a bug that they show up in the dir list of the root